# Input with side button on Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to do something like this: [image]
but When I try something in my code, just show that: [image]

that's my code:

```
<div class="lg:grid justify-center mt-4 flex">
    <BreezeInput2
        id="email"
        type="email"
        class="mt-1 block w-full focus:shadow-md"
        required
        autofocus
        autocomplete="username"
        placeholder="email@email.com"
      />
    <a class="rounded-md py-2 px-6 cursor-pointer tracking-wider text-md inline-table w-full
              items-center
              text-center bg-purple-600 text-white font-bold hover:bg-purple-600 hover:shadow-purple mt-3
            "
            :href="route('dashboard')"
          >
            Notify
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably start off by removing the [`grid`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#grid) style from your container since you already have a flexbox, and then adding [`flex-row`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-direction#row). After that, remove your `inline-table` utility from your anchor tag, and add a [`flex`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex) utility instead. This should get you on the right track!

Any other help that you need, let me know or throw it up here. https://play.tailwindcss.com/

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `<div class="lg:grid mt-4 flex">` to `<div class="justify-center mt-4 flex">` Because you apply already the flex class.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/XrWzizHo7d